# Android: How do I create a custom RadioButton with a drawable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-xml

I want to create a custom RadioButton or RadioGroup like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1exly.png)

I want a checkmark inside the selected radio button.

Here's what I've tried:

RadioGroup xml:

```
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:text="Radio 1"
                android:button="@null"
                android:background="@drawable/radio_button_selector" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Radio 2"
                android:button="@null"
                android:background="@drawable/radio_button_selector" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:text="Radio 3"
                android:button="@null"
                android:background="@drawable/radio_button_selector" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

radio_button_selector.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="@color/colorRadioButtonSelected"/>
                    <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/checked_icon" />
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorRadioButtonUnselected"/>
            <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Here is the result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdqit.png)

How can I achieve a radiogroup as I want?

Comment: if my answer helped you or if it is correct according to your question, please, considere accepting it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First, create diferent shapes for each states such as checked, unchecked, or disabled in the `res/drawable` folder:

```xml
<shape android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorRadioButtonSelected"/>
    <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

Make them separeted from your selector will make you code a little cleaner.

Now, create your selector like this:

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_radio_button_checked" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_radio_button_unchecked" android:state_checked="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_radio_button_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

Notice that I've added an item for when the button is disable, which might be important. But if it's not, just remove it.

Then, use your selector like this on your layout:

```xml
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Radio 2"
    android:button="@drawable/radio_button_selector" />
```

Comment: I've created different shapes for each state as you mentioned. But now I have another problem: I can't see the button of the radiobutton at first. I can only see its text. But when I select that radio button I can see the button. How to see the button even if radiobutton isn't selected?

Comment: Did you put this code on your selector? <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_radio_button_unchecked" android:state_checked="false" />. If there's no item for when the radiobutton state_checked is "false", I'm pretty sure nothing will apear

Comment: Yes I put this code. But it's very interesting, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Give your radiobutton a custom style:

```
<style name="MyRadioButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/custom_btn_radio</item>
</style>
```

custom_btn_radio.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
   <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />

   <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on_pressed" />
   <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off_pressed" />

   <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on_selected" />
   <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off_selected" />

   <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />
   <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
</selector>
```

Replace the drawables with your own drawables.